# Why is Lie derivative smooth?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a linear Lie group, say $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth. The Lie derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$ is the function $\mathcal{L}_X f:G\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $$\mathcal{L}_X f(y):=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}f\left(ye^{tX}\right).$$ Why is $\mathcal{L}_X f$ smooth? In his book on $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, Lang just says so without any comment (p. 90), but I failed to provide a rigorous justification up to now. A reference is also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the map $$\phi:G\times\Bbb R\to G,~(g,t)\mapsto g\exp(tX)$$ is smooth, as it is obtained from the smooth map $\Bbb R\to G,~t\mapsto \exp(tX)$ and the smooth map $\mu:G\times G\to G,~(g,g')\mapsto gg'$. The Lie derivative of $f$ is the derivative with respect to $t$ of the smooth map $$f\circ\phi:G\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,~(g,t)\mapsto f(\phi(g,t))$$ and it is thererfore smooth.

---

To be $100\%$ precise (and pretty pedantic), it is obtained as the composite
$$\begin{array}{c}
G&\to &T(G\times\Bbb R)&\to& T\Bbb R\simeq \Bbb R\times\Bbb R&\to&\Bbb R\\
g&\mapsto& {\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\bigg|_{(g,0)}&\mapsto & T_{(g,0)}(f\circ\phi)\bigg({\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\bigg|_{(g,0)}\bigg)= \underbrace{\lambda}_{=\mathcal L_Xf(g)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{f(g)}&\mapsto&\lambda
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I would paraphrase the first part of your answer as follows: The mapping $(y,t)\mapsto f(y e^{tX})$ is smooth, so its pullback to local coordinates around any point of the form $(y,0)$ is smooth, the same being true of the partial derivative of this pullback with respect to the last variable. Of course, evaluation at zero of this partial derivative is also smooth, but this is nothing but $\mathcal{L}_X f$ in local coordinates.

Comment: @MuratGüngör You can certainly put it that way. As you note, it essentially boils down to the fact that when a map is smooth, so are (by definition!) its partial derivatives.